# Why can't Clementine be fixed?

Tags: westworld-2016

In Westworld, when Clementine is lobotomised in S1E7, humans and hosts alike, in subsequent episodes, act as if she is completely beyond repair. Yet we have seen hosts suffer massive damage and either be repaired or rebuilt. Maeve certainly knows this, as do Felix and Sylvester, and Bernard knows that all the hosts are backed up in The Cradle. I have recently re-watched and can see no explanation for this - have I missed something, or have Joy & Nolan ever addressed this in interviews?

Comment: It has been a minute, but I think they assumed her issues were software related. Looking at a synopsis online that is when she goes crazy and starts killing "people" and they are unsure how corrupt the programming is. If I remember right it is mentioned at some point that the hosts all link together and share data so they were concerned that whatever the "virus" was could get spread to the other hosts and actual guests could begin to get harmed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In S3E7 she

> actually *is* repaired so this question is moot.